# Got IE stop running script error using JQuery datatable

Tags: jquery, performance, datatable

I am using JQuery datatable plugin. I only have 5000 rows, 8 columns but I keep getting the IE alert says: Stop running script error.

I am using JSON source for the data table. But seems it is not doing real pagination, I am not familiar with PHP, not sure how to do server side processing by using php...

here is the data configurations for the data table:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
                          //"sScrollX": "100%",
                          //"sScrollXInner":  "150%",
                          "sScrollY": '350px',
                          "aLengthMenu": [[10, 30, 50, 100], [10, 30, 50, 100]],
                          "bJQueryUI": true,
                          //"bDeferRender": true,
                          //"bStateSave": true, //store the table state in localStorage and then load it back again when needed using cookies
                          'iDisplayLength': 30,
                          //"bPaginate": false,
                          "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                          //disable init sorting
                          "aaSorting": [],
                          "fnPreDrawCallback":function(){
                                $("#processDiv").show();
                      },
                      "fnDrawCallback":function(){//"fnInitComplete"
                          $("#processDiv").hide();
                      },

                      "bProcessing": true,
                      "sAjaxSource": "<%= dataTableStorageDir %>",
                      "aoColumns": [
                          { "mData": "cells.0.displayText" },
                          { "mData": "cells.1.displayText" },
                          { "mData": "cells.2.displayText" },
                          { "mData": "cells.3.displayText" },
                          { "mData": "cells.4.displayText" },
                          { "mData": "cells.5.displayText" },
                          { "mData": "cells.6.displayText" },
                          { "mData": "cells.7.displayText" }
                      ],

                      "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
                      $('td',nRow).each(function(i,v){
                                if (typeof aData.cells[i].title!='undefined'){
```

any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is enough php code provided in server-side example to get you started by simply changing column array and db connection parameters

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html

5000 rows is not insignificant when it comes to html tables